# Haskell check if object is moving diagaonal or not

Tags: haskell

If on a 4x5 chessboard i have a soldier with (x,y) coordinates and i need it to move to another (x',y') coordinate which is a diagonal movement how would i argument it on Haskell?.i need to implement a function isDiagonal. its a 4x5 board so there are 20 squares in total. for example if soldier one is on coordniate (1,1) and i want it to move to (2,2) which is a diagonal movement to then give me a " True return" how would i write it ?

Comment: You need to add more details. At present it is not at all clear what you are asking. How do you describe the movement? Which direction? How many squares? What if it goes off the board?

Comment: @PaulJohnson i did edit it now. hope it's clearer. and there is no off board choice i just need to write it as simple as possble if the movement is diagonal (True) and everything else doesnt matter as it is " false"

Comment: And more effort. Usually you better first define the *signature* of the function, then you can think what patterns can arise, then which cases those patterns have to cover, and finally assign output to each of those cases.

Comment: Furthermore why do you all of a sudden delete your previous no-attempt question and change your username?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem somehow i feel stupid for asking all those questions at once Sorry again. it's just my first week on it and really trying to learn thi stuff

Comment: @Demiss: well there is no problem with *being new* to something, but somehow, the question(s) do not show much effort. Even if you do not manage to get the Haskell syntax (perfectly) right, then you can still invest effort in it. For example come up with a signature, explain in your own words (or pseudocode) how you would tackle the problem in general.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry if ii seems i am not giving effort. based on your advice i managed to solve the problem. i first defind the Function
isDiagonal :: (Int, Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
isDiagonal (x,y) (x',y')  = if x == 1 && y == 1 &&  x' == 2 && y' == 2 then True else False.

Comment: Try `isDiagonal (x,y) (x',y') = abs (x - x') == abs (y - y')` consider inputs like `(3,4) (4,5)` or `(3,5) (4,4)` or `(0,0) (20,20)`. But also note `(0,0) (0,0)`.

Comment: @Demiss notice that the statement `if x then True else False` is just equivalent to `x`.